# Wondering what the phrase "as clumsy as it may seem" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Don't extend your hand because some people take it and pull you in. **As clumsy as it may seem**, wave from afar and jump right into the conversation as you're approaching them. By the time you get to them, the greeting phase is clearly over. It would be socially awkward to kiss your cheek after you're well into the conversation. The key is ending the greeting phase as quickly as you can and distance.

My perception: Wave from afar in a clumsy way, like you know that it is care less and do it confidently!

Comment: it seems archaic - wave from, afar...what is the reference?

Comment: @Inquist - I've always advised people to wait 12-24 hours before accepting an answer. That gives sufficient time for an answer to be read and critiqued, and for other answers to be added. **If the O.P. knew the correct answer, there would be no need to ask the question**, so how can an O.P. distinguish between a good and bad answer right away? Moreover, I've seen times when an O.P. got an answer, accepted it just an hour or two later, and it turned out to be a crummy answer that wasn't even correct. There's no need to rush the acceptance process, and three hours is hardly too long to delay.

Comment: I said that to someone just a couple of days ago. He accepted my answer just a couple of hours after posting the question. I encouraged him to unaccept my answer! Partly because I kind of thought a more complete answer might come along and partly because 12 hours+ is just a good general rule.

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of important to understand the context here. The whole point of the paragraph is that it is giving advice about how to avoid being kissed by someone who kisses as a greeting. So, the waving from afar has a purpose, it's to get past the "greeting stage" before you're close enough to kiss. It may seem *clumsy* (or awkward works here too), but there is a reason for it. *As clumsy as it may seem*, there is a point to it. No matter how *clumsy it may seem*, do it, or you're going to get kissed. Get it?